# Proving this limit as $x \rightarrow ∞$?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I'm having trouble proving this using epsilon-delta:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left|\frac{x}{x+1}\right|=1$$

I translated this into:

$$\forall \epsilon>0,∃\delta\in\mathbb R,x>\delta\implies \left|\frac{x}{x+1}-1\right|<\epsilon$$

I don't really know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Calculate $\Bigl|\dfrac x{x+1}\Bigr| -1$, to begin with.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $x>0$ and start from here to find $\delta$

$$\left|\frac{x}{x+1}-1\right|<ε\iff \left|\frac{-1}{x+1}\right|<ε\iff 0<\frac{1}{x+1}<ε$$

$$\iff x+1>\frac{1}{ε} \iff x>\frac{1}{ε}-1=\delta $$

Comment: Are we allowed to ignore $x<0$?

Comment: @Mathingmatics Yes of course if the limit is to $+\infty$ we can consider the case x positive.

Answer (score 3):

Try observing that
$$
\left|\frac{x}{x+1}-1\right|=\left|\frac{x-x-1}{x+1}\right|
=\left|\frac{1}{x+1}\right|
$$

Comment: How do you get rid of the absolute value?

Comment: @Mathingmatics You can assume $x>0$, so…